# Timber Shopify Theme Push/Pull columns based on screen size

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid, timber

Been stuck on this shopify html template that's using the Timber CSS framework.
https://github.com/Shopify/Timber/blob/master/assets/timber.scss.liquid

I need to swap two divs with the class

> grid__item

if the user is on a mobile device.

Below is the code that I have.
I have no idea on how to make the swap. 
I believe bootstrap refers to this as push/pull?

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item one-half medium-down--one-whole">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item one-half medium-down--one-whole">2</div>
</div>
```

In mobile I'd like the div with "2" to shown first, and then "1".

Comment: can you apply CSS??

Comment: U mean if I can give more css styles, classes etc?

Comment: No, I am asking if you could apply CSS if you can then give `grid` `display: flex;` and give `order: 0;` to second child and `order: 1;` to first child.

Answer (score 0):

Timber has options for push and pull

https://github.com/Shopify/Timber/blob/master/assets/timber.scss.liquid#L38

So, to achieve the order change on mobile you should or put the items reversed in markup for desktop do `push and pull`, or use `flexbox` adding custom styles in .scss files of your theme